# how to plot a graph with different equations depending on the 'x' value

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
dx = 0.1
x = 0:dx:30:
for x<5,     f(x)= 0.1*(x^4)-5.6*(x^3)+3.6*(x^2)–16.2*(x^3)+6.2*(x^2)+11.5*(x)-9.8 
for 5<=x<20, f(x)= 0.4*(x^3)+1.2(x^2)+9.7*(x)–89.6
for 20<=x,   f(x)= 0.8*(x^2)+8.9*(x)-8.2
```

I have tried using a for loop with if and elseif statements but cant make it work, if someone could help that would be great

Comment: What did your for-loop look like?

Comment: for x=0:dx:30                                                                                                                                           if x<5  f(x)= 0.1*(x^4)-5.6*(x^3)+3.6*(x^2)–16.2*(x^3)+6.2*(x^2)+11.5*(x)-9.8             elseif 5<=x<20  f(x)= 0.4*(x^3)+1.2(x^2)+9.7*(x)–89.6                                                             else 20<=x  f(x)= 0.8*(x^2)+8.9*(x)-8.2      end      end

Answer (score 1):

A piecewise function that uses a symbolic variable `syms x` might suffice in this case.  The piecewise function allows you to plot multiple functions over only a distinct bounds/regions.  It is also possible with anonymous functions and different `x` vectors as input.

[image: Piecewise Plot]

```
syms x

f1=0.1*(x^4)-5.6*(x^3)+3.6*(x^2)-16.2*(x^3)+6.2*(x^2)+11.5*(x)-9.8;
f2=0.4*(x^3)+1.2*(x^2)+9.7*(x)-89.6;
f3=0.8*(x^2)+8.9*(x)-8.2;

Bounds_1 = x<5;
Bounds_2 = 5<=x<20;
Bounds_3 = 20<=x;

y = piecewise(Bounds_1,f1,Bounds_2,f2,Bounds_3,f3);

fplot(y);
xlim([-5 50]);
```